# X fail: "Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration"

Tags: xorg, gui

I've been running 12.04 (64-bit) for quiet a while now without any major problems. But when trying to login in today, the GUI failed to come on and was stuck at a flashing cursor. I switched to a console (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>) to see what the problem is. Looking in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` I get the following failure line:
`(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration`

I thought it might be something to do with Nvidia drivers so I did a purge of the nvidia stuff (`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`) and reverted the xorg.conf file to the little failsafe one that uses vesa. But this still comes up with the same error, so I doesn't look like it's the nvidia stuff that's causing the problem.

I'm really stumped now, any ideas? I assume the last update has changed something, but I'm not sure what was updated that could have caused this.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it reconfiguring the GUI by executing:

```
Xorg -configure
dpkg --configure -a
```

and restarting. In my case it recovered the previous (correct configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade my Ubuntu to 23.04，and see the same problem.

Try:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo Xorg -configure
rm ~/.Xauthority
sudo copy /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

I don't know which one is the key operation, I do all of them, and solved the problem .